# Operaciones de substracción de medias agrupadas condicionadas a valores anteriores de una variable

Tags: r

Tengo un fichero de datos ([data.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bcwxhns109ewat8/data.csv?dl=0)) que contiene 4 variables (g, z, x, y). La variable g la trato como "Ronda" a continuación para facilitar la explicación.

Deseo obtener la media de y para cada agrupación de variables Ronda, z, x (es decir, para cada posible combinación de nieveles de Ronda, z, x). Lo hago así:

```
data %>%
  group_by(Ronda, z, x) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y), 
            desvio = sd(y),                             #Estimación de la media
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             #Error estandar de la estimación de la media. 
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),      #Techo del intervalo. 
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) %>%  #Piso del intervalo al 95%.
```

A las medias obtenidas en el apartado anterior me gustaría ahora restar las medias agrupadas en la ronda inmediatamente anterior. En pseudocódigo, algo así:

```
 mean(y) en Ronda, z, x - mean(y) en Ronda-1, z, x
```

Excepto en la primera Ronda que restaríamos la primera Ronda también.
Así pues:

A la media de la 1ª Ronda le restaríamos la media de la 1ª Ronda.

A la media de la 2ª Ronda le restaríamos la media de la 1ª Ronda.

A la media de la 3ª Ronda le restaríamos la media de la 2ª Ronda.

A la media de la 4ª Ronda le restaríamos la media de la 3ª Ronda.

[and so on...]

El propósito es llevar dicho resultado a un gráfico que genero así:

```
  ggplot(aes(x = Round, y = media_lag, color = z)) +
  labs(title=mytitle1) +
  geom_line(aes(group = z), size=0.5) + 
  labs(x = "Round", y = "y", color = "Tipo") +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("Low isolation", "Moderate isolation", "High isolation"), values = c("blue","green","red")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 7, by = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14))+
  facet_wrap(~x)
```

Donde y = media en este útimo gráfico correspondería a la resta que explico más arriba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a usar otra aproximación algo distinta y tal vez un poco más compleja a la de @mpaladino, la idea es lograr hacer un `left_join()` de los datos consigo mismos pero desplazados para poder obtener la media anterior.

```
data %>%
    rename("Ronda" = "g") %>% 
    group_by(Ronda, z, x) %>%
    summarise(media = mean(y, na.rm = T)) %>%
    arrange(Ronda, z, x) %>%
    mutate(Ronda_n = match(Ronda, unique({.}$Ronda)),
           Ronda_n_lag = Ronda_n - 1) %>%
    left_join(y={.}, c("Ronda_n_lag" = "Ronda_n", "z", "x")) %>%
    mutate(media_lag = ifelse(is.na(media.y),0,media.x-media.y)) %>%
    select(Ronda=Ronda.x, x, z, media=media.x, media_lag)
```

La primer parte es bastante básica: (1) Renombramos la columna `g` a `Ronda`, (2) Agrupamos, (3) Obtenemos la media (4) y ordenamos por `Ronda`, `z`, y `x`

Con:

```
mutate(Ronda_n = match(Ronda, unique({.}$Ronda)),
       Ronda_n_lag = Ronda_n - 1) %>%
```

Generamos un `id` numérico para cada grupo de `Ronda` y generamos un segundo `id` pero desplazado del original en 1. **Nota 1**: Podríamos trabajar directamente con `Ronda` y `Ronda-1` ya que este es un `id` numérico correlativo, pero de esta manera la solución es más generalizable.

Ahora sí, nos permite hacer:

```
left_join(y={.}, c("Ronda_n_lag" = "Ronda_n", "z", "x")) %>%
mutate(media_lag = ifelse(is.na(media.y),0,media.x-media.y)) %>%
select(Ronda=Ronda.x, x, z, media=media.x, media_lag)
```

Hacemos un`left_join` de los datos consigo mismos, `y={.}` es la forma de indicarlo, la particularidad es que el `join` lo hacemos entre `Ronda` y `Ronda-1`, esto para llegar a obtener la `media` de cada fila pero de la `Ronda` anterior. Con esto ya podemos calcular una `media_lag` que se corresponde a la `media_x` (Por ej. Ronda 2) menos `media_y` (En el mismo ejemplo sería Ronda 1). Por último, simplemente seleccionamos las columnas deseadas.

Comment: Es buena idea, al poner un número a cada grupo se pierde la ambigüedad implícita en `group_by(z,x)`

Comment: @mpaladino, si esa es la idea, aunque me parece mas "elegante" usar `lag`

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos de veras. He estado utilizando la versión sugerida en este post. Comprendo bien los pasos dados (aunque no habría sido capaz de elaborarlo por mí mismo). Parece que era un problema más complicado que a simple vista. Todo funciona bien y los cálculos parecen correctos. Sin embargo, al intentar pasarlo a ggplot para visualizarlo obtengo un error clásico (Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval). Utilizo el código del plot que puse en la pregunta añadiendo media_log. Pero me estoy perdiendo algo básico aquí que no veo!

Comment: @pyring, acabo de probar con tus datos, y luego de preprocesarlos con el código de mi respuesta, los grafico perfectamente bien con el código ggplot de tu pregunta (salvo por la línea del título que la he quitado). Suerte.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Patricio Moracho, parece ser que me faltaba una funcionalidad en una librería. Está resuelto eso ya. Ahora me quedan dudas sobre cómo implementar los CI's 95%. Entiendo que debería pasar por pasos similares utilizando summarise y mutate.

Comment: exactamente @pyring, agregas la función correspondiente en el `summarize` y en el `mutate` creas las nuevas variable replicando la misma mecánica que usamos con la media.

Answer (score 2):

## Respuesta corta

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  rename("Ronda" = "g") %>% 
  group_by(Ronda, z, x) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%        #Si no ordenaría dentro de c/grupo en el paso siguiente
  arrange(z, x) %>% 
  group_by(z,x) %>%   #Para que obtenga el default correcto en c/ grupo
  mutate(dif_media = media - lag(media, 
                                 n = 1, 
                                 default = media[1]))
```

Resultado

```
# A tibble: 63 x 5
# Groups:   z, x [9]
Ronda z                  x media dif_media
<int> <chr>          <int> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 High isolation     0 1       0      
2     2 High isolation     0 1.13    0.130  
3     3 High isolation     0 1.01   -0.120  
4     4 High isolation     0 1.01    0.00500
5     5 High isolation     0 0.978  -0.0375 
6     6 High isolation     0 1.02    0.0425 
7     7 High isolation     0 0.965  -0.055  
8     1 High isolation     1 1       0      
9     2 High isolation     1 2.68    1.68   
10    3 High isolation     1 5.19    2.51   
# ... with 53 more rows
```

## Explicación

usa `dplyr::lag()` para generar un vector "atrasado" en una posición. De ese modo podemos calcular la diferencia de medias. 
Para ubicar correctamente a cada fila y poder comparar por Ronda se reordena el data.frame de modo que, para cada combinación de `x` y `z` queda inmediatamente arriba el dato de la ronda anterior. Con `lag()` el dato de "arriba" queda a la par.

Después definimos nuevamente nuevamente los grupos a los datos ordenados, de modo que para cada grupo `lag()` comience con un valor default específico: el valor de la Ronda 1 para esa combinación `x` y `z`. 
Creo que soluciona los problemas de la respuesta original. Quizás introduzca otros...

> Se aceptan sugerencias de tests para ver en qué condiciones falla esta aproximación.

## Respuesta original

```
data %>%
  rename("Ronda" = "g") %>% 
  group_by(Ronda, z, x) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y, na.rm = T)) %>% #OJO: na.rm = no está en el ejemplo original.
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(dif_media = media - lag(media, n = 9, default = media[1]))
```

## Aclaraciones:

La clave está en la función `dplyr::lag()`, que te permite "atrasar" a un vector. Uno de sus argumentos es `n=`, en el que se indica cuantas posiciones atrasarlo. Aprovechando que todos tus grupos tienen el mismo largo (9) la solución consiste en atrasar el vector de comparación 9 lugares, entonces comparo a cada media con la media la media 9 filas arriba, es decir, de la Ronda anterior.

Con el argumento `default=` indica con qué valor vamos a "rellenar" las primeras filas. En este caso como en toda la Ronda la media es la misma uso el primer valor.

Funciona para este caso, pero no me gusta mucho la solución:

1. Fallaría sin dar un error si hay grupos con largos desiguales, ya que no compara grupos, compara posiciones.
2. Fallaría si las medias del primer grupo (Ronda) no son constantes. No encontré una manera de pasar un vector a `default=`, solo pude pasarle un escalar.
3. Tenemos que poner manualmente el input del largo de grupo. Esto es relativamente fácil de solucionar.

## Conclusión

Usar con mucho cuidado, está muy lejos de ser una solución general al problema.

> PD: quité las demás funciones del `mutate()` para enfocarme en el problema de las medias. Debería funcionar igual si dejas el cálculo de desvío, error, etc., pero de esta forma el ejemplo es más conciso.
>
> <del>Si encuentro una solución general al problema la agrego</del>

Answer (score 2):

## Solución con R base

```
   comparar_medias <- function(x) 
   {
    m <- matrix(x$media, ncol = length(unique(x$Ronda)))
    m_lag <- cbind(m[ ,1] , m[ ,1:ncol(m)-1])
    as.vector(m - m_lag)
   }

data_piryng %>%  #data es una función en R (*)
  rename("Ronda" = "g") %>% 
  group_by(Ronda, z, x) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(dif_medias = comparar_medias(.))
```

> `x` una data.frame o `.` si usamos `%>%`

En principio no tiene mucho caso hacerlo en R base, pq ya se está usando el tidyverse. De todos modos con esta solución:

- debería ser mucho más rápida al usar sustracción de matrices, que es rapida en R.
- El código es más legible:

  - m es una matriz con tantas columnas como grupos
  - m_lag es esa matriz atrasada una posición, con la primer columna repetida
  - el output es la diferencia entre esas dos matrices
- Al envolverlo en una función puedo asignar con la tranquilidad de no contaminar el entorno global y permito al garbage collector hacer su trabajo. Cerrada la función se libera la memoria utilizada.

Limitaciones:

- los nombres de columna tienen que ser los mismos. Se podría solucionar con `!!` o similar.
- **siempre** va a dar un error si los grupos tienen diferente largo. Esto puede ser bueno si tenemos la expectativa de que los grupos sean de igual tamaño. Un error acá podría señalar un problema con los datos, manipulación, etc.

> (*) R es de tipado muy débil, por eso la responsabilidad de cuidar los nombres es del/a usuario/a. ¡Nada me impide `pi = Inf`!

Comment: muchas gracias @mpaladino, quizá esta respuesta tiene la ventaja, como dices, de ser más legible para usuarios de R no profesionales, como yo. Creo que quizá utilizando este método sea más sencillo aplicar los CI's 95%.